# jQuery Template Formatting with Comma

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following template. I want to display the categories with a comma in between. How do I do it?

Currently it is without comma using `Categories: {{each categories}}  <i>${$value}</i>   {{/each}}`

Note: There should be no comma after the last item. Also all items should be displaying in one row (as it is currently)

```
<script id="Script1" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
    <h1>${postTitle}</h1>

    <p>
        ${postEntry}
    </p>

    {{if categories}}  
      Categories: {{each categories}}  <i>${$value}</i>   {{/each}}
    {{else}}
      Uncategorized
    {{/if}}

</script>



 <script type="text/javascript">
  var blogPostsArray = [
            {
                postTitle: "Learn jQuery",
                postEntry: "Learn jQuery easliy by following.... ",
                categories: ["HowTo", "Sinks", "Plumbing"]
            },
            {
                postTitle: "New Tests",
                postEntry: "This is a test website"
            }
        ];

  $("#blogPostTemplate").tmpl(blogPostsArray).appendTo("#blogPostContainerDiv");

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```
categories.join(', ');
```

to get your string value.  not sure where you would put this but this example seems to show how

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl/blob/master/demos/samplesCore/basic.html

EDIT:

Allow me to do it for you :):)

```
{{if categories}}  
  Categories: <i>${categories.join(", ")}</i>
{{else}}
  Uncategorized
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't get any simpler than this. You just change the line `Categories: {{each categories}}  <i>${$value}</i>   {{/each}}` in your template with `Categories: <i>${categories.join(", ")}</i>`. In fact it's even simpler than the original :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this instead:

```
<script id="Script1" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
    <h1>${postTitle}</h1>

    <p>
        ${postEntry}
    </p>

    {{if categories}}  
      Categories: ${categories}
    {{else}}
      Uncategorized
    {{/if}}

</script>



 <script type="text/javascript">
  var blogPostsArray = [
            {
                postTitle: "Learn jQuery",
                postEntry: "Learn jQuery easliy by following.... ",
                categories: ["HowTo", "Sinks", "Plumbing"].join(', ')
            },
            {
                postTitle: "New Tests",
                postEntry: "This is a test website"
            }
        ];

  $("#blogPostTemplate").tmpl(blogPostsArray).appendTo("#blogPostContainerDiv");
</script>
```

The line `categories: ["HowTo", "Sinks", "Plumbing"].join(', ')` joins the array of strings into one string, separated by commas. Also changed the template so that it just prints the categories instead of looping.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more complicated data, say:

```
var blogPostsArray = [
            {
                postTitle: "Learn jQuery",
                postEntry: "Learn jQuery easliy by following.... ",
                categories: 
                [
                    {
                        Name="Category 1", 
                        Description="Category 1 description"
                    },
                    {
                        Name="Category 2", 
                        Description="Category 2 description"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                postTitle: "New Tests",
                postEntry: "This is a test website"
            }
        ];
```

You can do the trick in this way (this also acceptable for your data):

```
{{if categories }}
    <div>
        Categories: 
        {{each(i, category) categories}}
            ${category.Name}
            $(category.Description)
            {{if categories.length != (i + 1) }}
            ,
            {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
{{/if}}
```

Hope this helps somebody.